# Youtube video in bootstrap not working

Tags: youtube, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use a YouTube video on my Bootstrap page, but for some reason the sample video is working but video which I put isn't working on page.

Here is the code: https://codepen.io/brachu21/pen/QOJNXd.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h2>16:9 Responsive Aspect Ratio</h2>
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ePbKGoIGAXY"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h2>4:3 Responsive Aspect Ratio</h2>
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Th29zm5u8yM"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    background: #e3e3e3;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
h1,
h4 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
h1 i {
    color: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have the wrong version of the YouTube video. You need to use an embed link. Try using this link for the second video: https://www.youtube.com/embed/Th29zm5u8yM

```css
.container {
    background: #e3e3e3;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
h1,
h4 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
h1 i {
    color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h2>16:9 Responsive Aspect Ratio</h2>
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ePbKGoIGAXY"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h2>4:3 Responsive Aspect Ratio</h2>
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Th29zm5u8yM"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the embed URL.

You should change your URL to https://www.youtube.com/embed/Th29zm5u8yM